# Get custom attribute in final price method

Tags: php, attributes, custom, magento2.1.6

I would like to add a custom attribute (bum) in the final_price.phtml file.

I put this code:
[image]

It doesn't work, nothing appears. Can you help me please?

When I tried, `<?php echo $_product->getBum();` I have this error message :

[image]

Fatal error: Call to a member function getBum() on null in /home/magento/www/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml on line 33

Thanks,

Comment: is final_price.phtml custom file you created ?

Comment: when you print_r($_product), are you able to see your attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is product custom attribute, you can try

```
echo $_product->getBum();
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your repply. When I tried your answer, I have this error message : Fatal error: Call to a member function getBum() on null in /home/magento/www/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml on line 33

Comment: Do you know why? Thanks,